# Undefined variable with static scope variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem when using 'static' in PHP. Here is my code:

```
static $a = 12;
if(0) {
static $b = 11;
static $a = 11111;
}
echo $a.'----------'.$b;
```

why the output is "11111----------" and get "Notice: Undefined variable: b"

Comment: are you sure about your usage of `static` please see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: @DarthVader that does technically work...

Comment: why the output is "11111----------" and $b is Undefined variable

Comment: yeah just saw that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @binpang $b is undefined because of the scope.

Answer (score 2):

It must be a scope issue, but I'm not sure *why* since it's not in a function.  Either way, I got it working like this:

```
static $a = 12;
static $b; // <-- notice this
if (0) {
    static $b = 11;
    static $a = 11111;
}
echo $a.'----------'.$b;
```

Comment: @DarthVader But why? It's not in a function..  This must be some hidden "feature" of PHP that I was not privy to.

Comment: no it s not. if you define $b in your `if` then you cant use it outside the `if` same thing in all languages.

Comment: @DarthVader That is not true.  The only thing the would happen is PHP would trigger an Undefined Variable Notice.  In _normal_ use cases that is.  I am not sure about this particular use of the `static` keyword..

Comment: remove the static keyword and try.

Comment: @DarthVader Actually, PHP is unique in this sense. Example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/whc-bvf

Comment: That is because `if (0)` always results in `false`.  The code block inside the `if` statement is never reached.  But for some reason, that is not the case with static non-class vars..

Comment: @AlexLunix interestingly enough, I did find a note in the PHP docs that said this: `Note: Static declarations are resolved in compile-time.`  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @DarthVader I prefer the term "unique", but I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please refer the below code snippet

```
 <?php 
     static $a = 12;
     static $b ;
     if(0) {
       static $b = 11;
       static $a = 11111;
      }

     echo $a.'----------'.$b;
    ?>
```

In the above code snippet variable $b is defined within if block .A variable defined within a conditional or loop block is accessible only within that block.so it needs to be globally declared .Then only it will be accessible in global scope

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#105925). Although it seems static variables are an exception.